# Node - How To Access Req in POST Route Middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new to Node and Express and I'm not sure how I can access `req` in a middleware function in a POST route.  Do I need to pass it in as a parameter?  There are other middleware functions in this route that access `req` but it is not being passed in.  Overall, I'm guess I'm confused as to how `req` works...

The function I'm referring to is `helpers.createPermissions()`

**My Route**

```
app.post('/oauth/authorize/decision', login.ensureLoggedIn('connect/signin'), helpers.createPermissions(req), oauth2.server.decision());
```

**The Function**

```
exports.createPermissions = function(req) {
  console.log(req);
};
```

**The Error**

```
ReferenceError: req is not defined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Middleware will always get passed three arguments: `req`, `res` and `next`.

So your middleware should look like this:

```
exports.createPermissions = function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req);
  // TODO: make sure you eventually call either `next` or send back a response...
};
```

And you can use it like this:

```
app.post('/oauth/authorize/decision', login.ensureLoggedIn('connect/signin'), helpers.createPermissions, oauth2.server.decision());
```

In situations where you see middleware being called as a function, it's because you're not calling the middleware itself, but a function that's *returning* a middleware function. For example:

```
var myMiddlewareWrapper = function() {
  // return the actual middleware handler:
  return function(req, res, next) {
    ...
  };
};

app.get('/', myMiddlewareWrapper(), ...);
```

This is usually done to pass extra options to the middleware handler (like with `login.ensureLoggedIn()`).

Comment: +1, it's worth mentioning that if your middleware has an arity of `4`, it's assumed to be `(err, req, res, next)`.

Comment: @maček I left that one out on purpose not to complicate matters, but you're absolutely right :)